# Prove that function is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $a>3/2$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Let $a>0$. I have to show that function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x,y):=\frac{x^{2a}+y^{2a}}{x^2+y^2}$$ 
when $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ and $f(0,0):=(0,0)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if $a>3/2$.

**My attempt:** I think it is very easy.
First let's notice that this function is symmetrical in regards to both arguments. Now I check if a partial derivative with respect to $x$ exists at $(0,0)$ and if it is continuous function.

Calculate:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h^{2a}}{h^2}\cdot h^{-1}$$
It is obvious that the above limit is finite only if $a\ge3/2$. Precisely, it is equal to $1$ when $a=3/2$ and equal to $0$ if $a>3/2$.

Now, we also see that partial derivative is continuous at $(0,0)$ whenever $a>3/2$. Now we will show that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ when $a=3/2$.

Consider a limit$$\lim_{(h,j)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{\frac{h^3+j^3}{h^2+j^2}-h-j}{h^2+j^2}$$.
After changing to radial coordiantes, we can show that this limit depends on an angle.

Is this all ok?

Comment: You have not written out a proof that the partial derivative is continuous at $(0,0)$ for $a > 3/2$. You should actually perform the differentiation and prove that the limit of the result is $0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. (That is, you should do the same procedure as you did to prove it is not continuous when $a=3/2$, deriving the opposite conclusion). Everything else looks fine.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You seem to want to use the fact that continuous partial derivatives implies differentiability, but you never checked that the partial derivatives are continuous.And the problem is an equivalence, you seem only be dealing with one direction. At the end you just treat the case $a=\frac 3 2$ and I'm not sure why. In any case all of your assertions are true.

Comment: because when $a=3/2$ partial derivatives are not continuous I believe. I ommitted calculations so this post doesnt get too long. Written just my results. As for the opposite direction, I should check that if $a>3/2$ then this function is differentiable, yes? But I already checked it, didnt I?

Comment: Up until "Now, we also see that partial derivative is continuous" I just see you prove that the partial derivatives at the origin exist if, and only if, $a\ge \frac 3 2$. After that I just see you prove that it is not differentiable at the origin when $a=\frac 3 2$.